# Search User By PK vs. Username Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, seo, primary-key, lookup

I'm defining a custom route for SEO and trying to decide whether the URL should look like site.com/user/userid/username vs site.com/user/username where user is the controller and the other two are self explanatory. Now, when I think about MS's Membership, it stores in the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie the username and the user can be searched using it. I've read another article that says to keep the id and add the username or product name, what have you as having the id allows for faster lookups. What do you think is the best way to go? I'd rather not carry the ID in the url. When I set the authcookie, I could carry it in there instead of the username I guess but it just doesn't feel right that I'd call it with User.Identity.Name, but that's just me. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will search for users by username on Google so from an SEO standpoint it doesn't matter. You only need to optimize those pages which have the potential to get (valuable) traffic.

Anyway, the search performance by name will be excellent as this column is indexed.

Comment: I'm not using the default Membership system so I guess I'll have to look into manually indexing a column. And I guess they really wouldn't search them by username but I'm just wondering about things like how facebook users come up if you search someone specifically by their name. You'll see links come up like facebook.com/johndoe where you can view their profile.

Comment: On my websites, I usually have a database column called UrlName which is unique and indexed. It put that one into the URL. I make sure it is nicely formatted and URL-safe.